# How to check that element of a list of lists matches a condition?

Tags: r, list, match

I have a list of lists:

```
  pairs <- list(
    list(Name="A",Value=11), 
    list(Name="B",Value=17), 
    list(Name="C",Value=23)
  )
```

How can I check that `pairs` list contains an element with Name=="A"?
And I'd also like to get that element.

Comment: Try `sapply(pairs, function(x) x[grep('Name',names(x))]=='A')`

Comment: @akrun Error in x[grep("Name", names(x))] : 
  object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Comment: Using your example I get `#Name  Name  Name 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE ` as result

Comment: Or maybe `temp <- unlist(pairs) ; temp[names(temp) == "Name" & temp == "A"]`

Comment: @akrun Yes, just mistyped. And how do I get a single bool value from this vector?

Comment: Try `library(rlist);list.filter(pairs, Name=='A')`

Comment: I am not sure what your expected output is.  I added the `rlist` version as this gives the key and value pair

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to know whether *any* list component has `Name=='A'`:

```
any(sapply(pairs,function(x) x$Name=='A'));
## [1] TRUE
```

If you want the number of list components that have `Name=='A'`:

```
sum(sapply(pairs,function(x) x$Name=='A'));
## [1] 1
```

If you want the `Value` of the list component(s) that have `Name=='A'`:

```
unlist(lapply(pairs,function(x) if (x$Name=='A') x$Value));
## [1] 11
```

If you want the sublist of components that have `Name=='A'`:

```
pairs[sapply(pairs,function(x) x$Name=='A')];
## [[1]]
## [[1]]$Name
## [1] "A"
##
## [[1]]$Value
## [1] 11
```

If you want the first inner list that has `Name=='A'` (can drop the `[1]` if you're certain there will only be one match):

```
pairs[[which(sapply(pairs,function(x) x$Name=='A'))[1]]];
## $Name
## [1] "A"
##
## $Value
## [1] 11
```

---

Alternatively, since your data appears to be regular, you can convert to a data.frame, which will simplify all these operations:

```
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(pairs,as.data.frame));
df;
##   Name Value
## 1    A    11
## 2    B    17
## 3    C    23
```

Here are the equivalents for `df`:

```
any(df$Name=='A');
## [1] TRUE
sum(df$Name=='A');
## [1] 1
df$Value[df$Name=='A'];
## [1] 11
subset(df,Name=='A');
##   Name Value
## 1    A    11
subset(df,Name=='A')[1,];
##   Name Value
## 1    A    11
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `Filter` if your `list` of `lists` has only one level. this will return the desired element(s):

```
> Filter(function(u) u$Name=='A', pairs)
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$Name
#[1] "A"

#[[1]]$Value
#[1] 11
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rlist`

```
library(rlist)
list.filter(pairs, Name=='A')
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$Name
#[1] "A"

#[[1]]$Value
#[1] 11
```

Also, my original version is

```
 sapply(pairs, function(x) x[grep('Name',names(x))]=='A') 
 # Name  Name  Name 
 # TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: this seems to be a nice package.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel  Some wrapper functions are in the package.